# TypeError when using Systemjs loaded class

Tags: javascript, systemjs, karma-mocha

I am once again puzzled by Javascript.  I am using Systemjs as a module loader and have a class as follows:

```
  export default class Tool{
  constructor(state, displayText) {

    this._state = state;
    this._displayText = displayText;
  }

  get displayText() {
    return this._displayText;
  }

  get state() {
    return this._state;
  }

}
```

I am using this class in a unit test (Karma/Mocha/Chai) as follows:

```
'use strict';
import Tool from '../core/model/framework/Tool';
import chai from '../../../jspm_packages/npm/chai@3.5.0';

chai.should();

describe('MenuProvider', () => {
  describe('registration', () => {
    it('should register a new Workbench Module', ()=> {
      let tools = [];

      debugger;

      tools.push(new Tool('Pink Fuzzy Bunnies', 'bunnyState'));
      tools.push(new Tool('Look no hands', 'nohandsstate'));


      let toolboxes = [];
      toolboxes.push(new Toolbox('My Shiny New Toolbox', tools));

      let newModule = new WorkbenchModule('My Module', toolboxes);

      let providerUnderTest = new MenuProvider();

      providerUnderTest.loadModule(newModule);

      provider.modules.count.should.equal(1);
      provider.getModule('My Module').should.not.be.null;

    });
  });
});
```

When I hit the debugger statement Tool is undefined.  I am pretty sure I have jspm configured properly for my Karma test. I can see that every file is loading correctly when I debug the Karma test.

Is there something I am missing?  I would just like to be pointed in the right direction.  Let me know if I need to add more of my code or config.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't exporting your class. Add this to the bottom of your `Tool` file:

```
export default Tool;
```

Answer (score 0):

I was in fact exporting my class on the first line.  The problem turned out to be related to the fact that Javascript does not hoist classes.  Basically the tests were trying to use the classes before they were loaded by Karma and JSPM.  I was able to resolve the issue by explicitly loading the files by adding the following to my config file:

```
jspm: {
  config: 'jspm.conf.js',
  loadFiles: ['src/app/angular-bootstrap.js', 'src/app/core/model/**/*.js', 'src/app/**/*.spec.js'], //'src/app/**/!(*.e2e|*.po).js'
  serveFiles: ['src/app/**/*.+(js|html|css|json|*jade*)'] // *.{a,b,c} to *.+(a|b|c) https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/1532
}
```

This is what did the trick: **'src/app/core/model**/**/*.js'**

Just as a tangential note.  I also had fits over why Karam was not loading my Jade files so I could import them using JSPM.  All I had to do was add the .jade extension to the list of file types being served up by Karma.

Such as a strange and wonderful world this Javascript stuff is!